# Are there public distcc servers?

Tags: c++, c, cloud, distcc

I have started using distcc, and I was wondering whether there were public distcc servers, that anyone could use?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: you're probably mistaking distcc with ccache.

Comment: Note that this might not make that much sense over the internet, the files to be sent over can become quite large, and soon the advantage of cpu speed might be overcome by the penalty of bandwidth